On $\dim \mathfrak{m}/ \mathfrak{m^2}$ for a local ring $(A,\mathfrak{m})$
I am trying to show that for every pair of integers $(s,t)$, there exists a Noetherian local ring $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ such that $s=\dim A \leq \dim(\mathfrak{m}/ \mathfrak{m^2})=t$ (the inequality is clear by Matsumoto 14 p.104).
To do so, I was thinking of considering an affine algebraic variety $X$ of rank s, and $\mathcal{O}_P$ the ring of rational functions on $X$ defined at $P$, whose Krull dimension is thus $s$.
Then, by Hartshorne I.5.1, we have $\dim(\mathfrak{m}/ \mathfrak{m^2})$ is the dimension of the tangent space of $X$ at $P$.
Then, considering $(f_1,\dots,f_m)\in k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ the ideal defining $X$, and $r$ the rank of the Jacobian matrix of the $(f_i)$, we have $\dim(T_P(X))=n-r$.
Now, I am wondering if it is possible to construct explicitly such $X$ and $P$ such that $\dim X = s $ and $\dim(T_P(X))=t$ ?
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Sure, you can do this without a ton of trouble. Consider $R = k[x_1,\cdots,x_t]_{(x_1,\cdots,x_t)}/(x_{s+1}^2,\cdots,x_t^2)$. The dimension of this ring is the same as the dimension of $R/\sqrt{(0)}\cong k[x_1,\cdots,x_s]_{(x_1,\cdots,x_s)}$, which is $s$; as $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2 = \operatorname{Span} \{x_1,\cdots,x_t\}$, it is $t$-dimensional over $k$.
